# Realm Object is not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using Realm in my project and I was trying to update the realm object through RxJava. Realm object is successfully stored but the realm object is not updated.Actually i am performing all Read operations on UI thread and all WRITE operations on background thread using RxJava. Below is my code to perform all Realm's read and write operations.

```
class SuggestedFriendsController internal constructor(realm : Realm) {
private var realm: Realm? = null

init {
    this.realm = realm
}

fun addSuggestedFriends(requestPojo: RequestPojo?) {
    realm?.executeTransaction { realm ->
        val realmFriends = RealmSuggestedFriends()
        realmFriends.friendEmail = requestPojo?.email
        realmFriends.friendImage = requestPojo?.image
        realmFriends.friendName = requestPojo?.name
        realmFriends.friendStatus = requestPojo?.status
        realmFriends.friendThumbImage = requestPojo?.thumb_image
        realmFriends.friendUid = requestPojo?.uid
        realmFriends.requestSent = "No"
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmFriends)
    }
}


fun getRequestStateSync(uid: String?): String? {
      var res =  Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
          realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
              ?.equalTo("friendUid", uid)
              ?.findFirst()
      }
    return res?.requestSent
}

fun getAllAsync() = Observable.create<List<RealmSuggestedFriends>> { emitter ->
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        val results = realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                ?.findAll()
        emitter.onNext(realm?.copyFromRealm(results)!!)
    }
}.flatMapIterable { list -> list }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

fun updateSuggestedFriendAsync(uid: String?, request_type: String?) =
        Single.create<String>{emitter ->
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().use {realm ->
                    realm?.executeTransaction{ realm ->
                        var suggested = realm.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                                .equalTo("friendUid", uid)
                                .findFirst()!!
                        suggested.requestSent = request_type
                        realm.insertOrUpdate(suggested)
                    }
                emitter.onSuccess("success")
                }
            }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

}

Below is my activity code. Here the variable `suggestedFriendController?.getRequestStateSync(friend_uid)` value is remain unchanged even its value is changed in the database.

```
class SFriend : AppCompatActivity(){
private var image : NewCircularImagview ?= null
private var name : AppCompatTextView ?= null
private var addFriend : AppCompatButton ?= null
private var imageUrl : String ?= null
private var toolbar : Toolbar ?= null
private var toolbar_text : TextView ?= null
private var progressBar : ProgressBar ?= null
private var friend_uid : String ?= null
private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
private var uid: String? = null
private var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable ?= null
private var realm : Realm ?= null
private var suggestedFriendController : SuggestedFriendsController ?= null
private var request_state : String ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.suggested_friend_profile)
    initialize()
  friend_uid = intent.getStringExtra("friend_uid")
  imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("imageurl")
  name?.text = intent.getStringExtra("name")
  request_state = suggestedFriendController?.getRequestStateSync(friend_uid)
    if (request_state?.equals("No")!!){
        addFriend?.setText("Send Request")
    }else{
        addFriend?.text = "Cancel Request"
    }
}
private fun initialize() {
compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
databaseReference?.keepSynced(true)
uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
image = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)
name = findViewById(R.id.name)
addFriend = findViewById(R.id.addFriend)
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar_text = toolbar?.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text1)
toolbar_text?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
suggestedFriendController = realm?.let { r-> SuggestedFriendsController(r) }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    progressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl!!).into(image,object :Callback{
        override fun onSuccess() {
            progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onError() {
            showMessage("image loading failed")
        }
    })
    addFriend?.setOnClickListener {
        addFriend?.isEnabled = false
        if (request_state?.equals("No")!!) {
            sendRequest(friend_uid)
        }else{
            cancelRequest(friend_uid)
        }
    }
}

private fun cancelRequest(friend_uid: String?) {
    Single.create<String>{ subscriber ->
        databaseReference
                ?.child("friend_requests")
                ?.child(uid)
                ?.child(friend_uid)
                ?.removeValue()
                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                        subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                        }
                    }else{
                        subscriber.onError(Throwable("error in cancel request"))
                    }
                }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { Single.create<String>{ subscriber ->
                        databaseReference
                                ?.child("friend_requests")
                                ?.child(friend_uid)
                                ?.child(uid)
                                ?.removeValue()
                                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                    if (task.isSuccessful){
                                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed){
                                            subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        subscriber.onError(Throwable("error in cancel request"))
                                    }
                                }
                     }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
            .subscribe({
                t1 -> showMessage(t1)
                addFriend?.text = "Send Request"
                addFriend?.isEnabled = true
                suggestedFriendController?.updateSuggestedFriend(friend_uid!!,"No")
            },{
                t2 -> showMessage(t2.message)
            })
}

private fun showMessage(message : String?) {
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun sendRequest(friend_uid : String?){
   var d =  Single.create<String>{ subscriber ->
                databaseReference
                ?.child("friend_requests")
                ?.child(uid)
                ?.child(friend_uid)
                ?.child("request_type")
                ?.setValue("sent")
                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful){
                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed){
                            subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                        }
                    }else{
                        subscriber.onError(Throwable("request failed"))
                    }
                }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { Single.create<String> { subscriber ->
                databaseReference
                        ?.child("friend_requests")
                        ?.child(friend_uid)
                        ?.child(uid)
                        ?.child("request_type")
                        ?.setValue("received")
                        ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful){
                                if (!subscriber.isDisposed){
                                    subscriber.onSuccess("sent")
                                }
                            }else{
                                subscriber.onError(Throwable("request failed"))
                            }
                        }
                }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }.flatMap {
       suggestedFriendController?.updateSuggestedFriendAsync(friend_uid,"Yes")
   }.subscribe({
      t1: String? -> showMessage(t1)
        addFriend?.text = "Delete Request"
        addFriend?.isEnabled = true
    },{
        t2 -> showMessage(t2.message)
    }
    )
   compositeDisposable?.add(d)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    finish()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    compositeDisposable?.clear()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    realm?.close()
}
```

}

Below code is my Realm model.

```
open class RealmSuggestedFriends : RealmObject(){
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var friendUid : String ?= null

@Required
var friendName : String ?= null

@Required
var friendEmail : String ?= null

@Required
var friendStatus : String ?= null

@Required
var friendImage : String ?= null

@Required
var friendThumbImage : String ?= null

@Required
var requestSent : String ?= null
}
```

I need your suggestions to make it work. Help me

Comment: There is not enough code here for me to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I updated my code. I hope everything is clear to you now. Please go through it. Thanks..

Comment: waiting for your suggestion mate.

Comment: Because you never registered a `RealmChangeListener` on the RealmObject (or a RealmResults containing the object). In fact, you only get the `requestSent` value. So of course it won't magically update itself in the Activity by itself.

Comment: okay but Realm documentation says "RealmObjects are live, auto-updating, you never have to refresh objects" .then why need to use change listener here..

Comment: Also if i finish my activity and restart it again then still my realm object's value is not refresh. Why it is happening this way?

Comment: Because you are working with `String`, and not `RealmSuggestedFriends`. Of course, technically I'm partly guessing. This is not canonical Realm usage - as anything involving `copyFromRealm()` isn't canonical Realm usage.

Comment: Is it necessary to use RealmChangeListener when working with multi-threading? .Because In my last project i used Realm but i never used RealmChangeListener and if any change in the value of realm object occurred then it also reflect on the UI thread. In that project I didn't used MultiThreading..

Comment: Yes, it reflects on the UI thread, *eventually*, which means you probably want to be notified about it when it's done.

Comment: No, its not working. I added a listener on Realm object that will give me the value of request sent. But when i restart my activity again, the old value is still coming up. its not reading the updated value..

Comment: If you successfully run the transaction, then this is possible only if you're using a detached object.

Comment: How would you do this?  Can you show me the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get the String, get the object. Also I wouldn't pass a Realm instance to a constructor of something like that.

```
class SuggestedFriendsController {

    fun addSuggestedFriends(requestPojo: RequestPojo) {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { r ->
            {
                r.executeTransaction { realm ->
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(RealmSuggestedFriends().apply {
                        friendEmail = requestPojo?.email
                        friendImage = requestPojo?.image
                        friendName = requestPojo?.name
                        friendStatus = requestPojo?.status
                        friendThumbImage = requestPojo?.thumb_image
                        friendUid = requestPojo?.uid
                        requestSent = "No"
                    })
                }
            }
        }


        fun getSuggestedFriend(realm: Realm, uid: String): RealmSuggestedFriends? =
            realm.where<RealmSuggestedFriends>().equalTo("friendUid", uid).findFirst()

        fun getAllAsync() = Single.create<List<RealmSuggestedFriends>> { emitter ->
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
                with(realm) {
                    emitter.onNext(copyFromRealm(where<RealmSuggestedFriends>().findAll())
                }
            }
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

        fun updateSuggestedFriendAsync(uid: String, requestType: String) =
            Single.create<String> { emitter ->
                Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { r ->
                    r.executeTransaction { realm ->
                        var suggested = realm.where<RealmSuggestedFriends>()
                            .equalTo("friendUid", uid)
                            .findFirst()!!
                        suggested.requestSent = requestType
                        realm.insertOrUpdate(suggested)
                    }
                    emitter.onSuccess("success")
                }
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    }

    class SFriend : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var image: NewCircularImagview
        private lateinit var name: AppCompatTextView
        private lateinit var addFriend: AppCompatButton
        private lateinit var imageUrl: String
        private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
        private lateinit var toolbar_text: TextView
        private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
        private lateinit var friend_uid: String
        private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
        private lateinit var uid: String
        private lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
        private lateinit var realm: Realm
        private lateinit var suggestedFriendController: SuggestedFriendsController
        private var suggestedFriend: RealmSuggestedFriends

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.suggested_friend_profile)
            initialize()
            friend_uid = intent.getStringExtra("friend_uid")
            imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("imageurl")
            name.text = intent.getStringExtra("name")
            suggestedFriend = suggestedFriendController.getRequestStateSync(realm, friend_uid)
            addFriend.text = when {
                "No" == suggestedFriend?.requestSent -> "Send Request"
                else ->
                    = "Cancel Request"
            }
            suggestedFriend.addChangeListener(RealmChangeListener {
                if(it.isValid()) {
                     addFriend.text = when {
                         "No" == it.requestSent -> "Send Request"
                         else -> "Cancel Request"
                     }
                }
            })
        }

        private fun initialize() {
            compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            databaseReference.keepSynced(true)
            uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
            image = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)
            name = findViewById(R.id.name)
            addFriend = findViewById(R.id.addFriend)
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
            toolbar_text = toolbar?.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text1)
            toolbar_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar!!.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            suggestedFriendController = SuggestedFriendsController()
        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(image, object : Callback {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                override fun onError() {
                    showMessage("image loading failed")
                }
            })
            addFriend.setOnClickListener {
                addFriend.isEnabled = false
                if ("No" == suggestedFriend?.requestSent) {
                    sendRequest(friend_uid)
                } else {
                    cancelRequest(friend_uid)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun cancelRequest(friend_uid: String?) {
            Single.create<String> { subscriber ->
                databaseReference
                    .child("friend_requests")
                    .child(uid)
                    .child(friend_uid)
                    .removeValue()
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                                subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                            }
                        } else {
                            subscriber.onError(Throwable("error in cancel request"))
                        }
                    }
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap {
                    Single.create<String> { subscriber ->
                        databaseReference
                            .child("friend_requests")
                            .child(friend_uid)
                            .child(uid)
                            .removeValue()
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                                        subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    subscriber.onError(Throwable("error in cancel request"))
                                }
                            }
                    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                }
                .subscribe({ t1 ->
                    showMessage(t1)
                    addFriend.text = "Send Request"
                    addFriend.isEnabled = true
                    suggestedFriendController.updateSuggestedFriend(friend_uid!!, "No")
                }, { t2 ->
                    showMessage(t2.message)
                })
        }

        private fun showMessage(message: String?) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        private fun sendRequest(friend_uid: String?) {
            var d = Single.create<String> { subscriber ->
                databaseReference
                    .child("friend_requests")
                    .child(uid)
                    .child(friend_uid)
                    .child("request_type")
                    .setValue("sent")
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                                subscriber.onSuccess("success")
                            }
                        } else {
                            subscriber.onError(Throwable("request failed"))
                        }
                    }
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap {
                    Single.create<String> { subscriber ->
                        databaseReference
                            .child("friend_requests")
                            .child(friend_uid)
                            .child(uid)
                            .child("request_type")
                            .setValue("received")
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                                        subscriber.onSuccess("sent")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    subscriber.onError(Throwable("request failed"))
                                }
                            }
                    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                }.doOnNext {
                suggestedFriendController.updateSuggestedFriendAsync(friend_uid, "Yes")
            }.subscribe({ t1: String? ->
                realm.refresh()
                showMessage(t1)
                addFriend.text = "Delete Request"
                addFriend.isEnabled = true
            }, { t2 ->
                showMessage(t2.message)
            })
            compositeDisposable.add(d)
        }

        override fun onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed()
            finish()
        }

        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            compositeDisposable.clear()
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            suggestedFriend.removeAllChangeListeners()
            realm.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but still its not working.. when i restart my activity, i get the old value of object even its value is changed. So whenever i restart my activity, my button text is set to "Send Request" .

Comment: Then you aren't actually persisting your changes into Realm for some reason.... Or you are actually saving it into another object. For example, the object you're saying doesn't have the uid marked with @PrimaryKey

Comment: No, my uid is marked with @PrimaryKey. I edited  my code. you can check my model class as well..

Comment: At this point, I'd recommend using a debugger and figuring out where exactly you don't get what you expect. What I wrote should theoretically work.

Comment: I debug the code and found that when the activity is restart, the UI thread is receiving the old data from Realm database even its data is changed. It might be possible that the two threads holding the copies of database and performing all transactions on separate copies.

Comment: Have you checked if your object's `isManaged()` property is true or false?

Comment: Then if after calling `realm.refresh()` it still has old value, that would mean the transaction was never committed on the background thread. So there is possibility that the transaction failed.

Comment: i checked the background thread. I used copyToRealmOrUpdate method and displayed the value through toast and its returning "Yes" means the object is updated in Realm database.

Comment: So where the problem is arising now.. everything is good here. object is also updating just the UI thread is watching the old value every time even after the application restarts. what should i do more..

Comment: Did you add the `realm.refresh()` in the subscribe method like I said?

Comment: yup. i used realm.refresh() in subscribe method like you used in your code.

Comment: If it doesn't update the Object, then the transaction failed / was never committed. Or the object is not managed (although you just said it is)

Comment: No. i receiving the updated value. i'm showing it by toast. it shows "yes" when i click send request button and after calling realm.refresh() in subscribe method, i'm getting the updated object but when i restart my activity, i got old object again.

Comment: I guess i figure it out where the problem is arising. I have two activities say A (User activity) and B (Sfriend activity) in my application. In user activity i'm fetching all registered users through Observable, adding them one by one in realm database and displaying them in Recyclerview. I didn't find any better option to keep my Realm synchronized with Firebase so i did this way.  when i send a request to user in activity B and return back to previous activity, my observable will again send the old value to Realm database. i think that's y i getting old value every time.

Comment: yes that was the problem. its work now. Thank you so much for helping me and giving me your valuable time.It was my coding mistake but whatever you told me so far and shared your code, its help me alot. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't expect Observable to `cache()`, unless it uses `replay(1)` or an underlying `BehaviorSubject` :| well, glad you found the error though!

Comment: I wasn't calling onComplete() method in Observable in my User activity. So when i return back to previous activity, i think data (which was set to default) in Realm database was updating again that's why I was getting old data everytime which i restarts  my SFriend activity.